Stylesheet properties not reflecting on the webpage due to MIME type
I am working on a project that runs a web server on a specified port written in Golang. The styling properies of the page don't reflect and the following error is logged on the browser console.
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:9000/static/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
My index.html file is in a folder named templates while the style.css file in a folder named static. This is how I specified the link relation of the stylesheet in the HTML file.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" />
The main.go file inside a folder named cmd is where I serve the static folder as illustrated below.
func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))

    http.HandleFunc("/", handlers.ServeIndex)

    port := ":9000"

    log.Printf("Server started at http://localhost%v", port)
    http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
}

Based on the provided information, what could be the issue leading to the problem?
I have tried clearing the browser's cache hoping the issue would be solved but that didn't solve the problem.
Project file structure

Enter the URL of the CSS file in the browser to confirm that the file is served correctly.  Perhaps you are getting a 404 response instead of the file you expect.

You need to fix this at the server end, not the browser end. The server is labelling the file incorrectly when it sends it to the browser. Fully featured web servers such as Apache contain a config file which associates file types with mime types. I don't know what Golang provides ... if it is more of a DIY solution, then you may need to handle this in your code. When a request is for a CSS file, you may need to set the content-type header as you respond. This post may be helpful.

There's no need to set the content-type as speculated in another comment.  http.FileServer calls mime.TypeByExtension to get the value of the response Content-Type header.  @BrettDonald The name of the language is "Go", not "Golang".
